# Realtek RTL8723AU not working on Linux Mint 18.1

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, drivers, realtek

I just installed Linux Mint 18.1 (Xfce) on my Lenovo Yoga 13. As with the 17 version my wifi card (realtek rtl8723au) did not work after installation and I tried to solve it as I did for the previous installation

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`

sudo apt-get install git    #git
cd /tmp
mkdir wifi    #Wifi
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au.git wifi    #driver
cd wifi
make && sudo make install
cd ..    #/tmp
sudo rm -r wifi
```

This worked perfectly in the previous case but not now.

**Edit**
I have found that if I disable and re-enable the wifi in the network menu it connects for about 1 minute but then stops working again and can not find any networks.

These are the responses to `lsusb` and `rfkill list all`:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b322 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2047:0855 Texas Instruments Invensense Embedded MotionApp HID Sensor
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:000a Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:1724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8723AU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bc2:ab24 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

.

```
rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have searched for tutorials to help me but I can not find one that works. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue and although the following post was specifically about rtl8723be it was helpful:

https://techcatalystblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/12/rtl8723be-wifi-fix-for-linux/

Specifically, the info on antenna selection.

In my case, I used the Realtek drivers included in kernel 4.4.0-104 which cover all 8xxxu versions See here: `/lib/modules/4.4.0.104-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek`

```
# load modules
$sudo modprobe -rv rtl8xxxu
# select the alternate antenna
$sudo modprobe -v rtl8xxxu ant_sel=2
```

To make the change permanent, modify `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` to include these options.